# how to display locations on a mapview from cordinates retrived from an online database in Android

Tags: android, maps

Hi:
i am  creating an android app that retrieves gps coordinates stored on an online database(sql),the using this coordinates obtained,it pinpoints them on a map,this points should be click able and when clicked should display more information about that point also retrieved from the same database.

I would like you to help me with this

Answer (score 0):

you have to override  onTap() methof of MapView and you can show extra information about the location on click of the particular marker.